# MS access 2010 SQL query Help

Tags: sql, pivot, ms-access-2010

How can i turn a table from this form:

```
S_ID          SUBJECT          MARK
1             English          90
1             Math             40
1             Computer         30
2             English          85
2             Math             10
2             Computer         06
3             English          10
3             Math             20
3             Computer         40
```

To this form

```
S_ID       English        Math         Computer
1          90             40           30
2          85             10           06
3          10             20           40
```

using SQL code,

I'm using MS Access 2010,

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT S_ID ,
       MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'English' THEN mark ELSE null END) AS English,
       MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'Math' THEN mark ELSE null END) AS Math,
       MAX(CASE WHEN subject = 'Computer' THEN mark ELSE null END) AS Computer
FROM myTable
GROUP BY S_ID
```

Comment: +1 You can omit the `else null`, an unmatched `case` returns `null` by default

Comment: i looking forward to test this,
thank you :)
@HansUp :Access supports SWITCH statement, is it the same as CASE WHEN?

Comment: Scorpi0: if you are going to add an `ELSE null` clause then shouldn't you also cast the `null` to the same type as `mark`?

Comment: @onedaywhen : Seriously, cast a null ? Are you serious ?

Comment: ...noting that neither `CASE` nor type casting `NULL` is supported by the Access database engine (ACE, Jet, whatever).

Comment: @Scorpi0: sure. Google for `case cast null`.

Answer (score 4):

You want a cross-tab query which will yield a column per subject;

```
TRANSFORM Sum(MARK) AS TotalMark
SELECT 
   S_ID
FROM marks
   GROUP BY S_ID
PIVOT SUBJECT;
```

Comment: -although it works, but i'm looking for something that would work with mysql also, a more general SQL approach

thanks you very much for your reply, and of course up voted :)

Comment: -the other thing is i don't want the total(cross-tab),I want a "list" of students as shown in my question. :)

Comment: So long as there is one-mark-per-student-per-subject then `SUM()` will be ok as you will only ever be summing one value, another aggregate  like `MIN()/MAX()` would likewise give the same result. For mySQL you can use Scorpi0's answer replacing `CASE` with `sum( if(itemname = 'english', mark, 0))` - access also has a similar `iif()` - I doubt your going to find a cross-database way of doing this elegantly, particularly if one of them is Access.

Comment: "I doubt your going to find a cross-database way of doing this elegantly, particularly if one of them is Access."

couldn't agree more

Answer (score 0):

if this is a one time exercise, you could use many statements, sequentially: something like this:

```
insert into new_table
select distinct s_id, 0,0,0
from old_table
```

then a series of updates

```
update new_table n
set english = (select english from old_table where s_id = n.s_id )
where s_id = n.s_id
```